# Como inverter os índices de um v-for com Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho um array que nomeei como "nomes", que inicialmente está vazio

```
nomes: []
```

Estou incluindo elementos nesse array com a função unshift(), para incluir elementos sempre no início do array e não no final dele, então faço isso da seguinte forma:

```
nomes.unshift("Leonardo")
nomes.unshift("Victor")
nomes.unshift("Guilherme")
```

Utilizarei o v-for para exibir os elementos do array na minha página como uma lista:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="nome in nomes">
     {{ nome }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

A saída será:

- Guilherme
- Victor
- Leonardo

Agora quero lista-los com um índice, então faço o seguinte:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="(nome, i) in nomes">
     {{ i }}: {{ nome }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

E a saída será

- 1: Guilherme
- 2: Victor
- 3: Leonardo

Mas eu quero que os índices sejam invertidos, ou seja, que eu tenha o seguinte resultado:

- 3: Guilherme
- 2: Victor
- 1: Leonardo

Como faço para inverter a ordem dos índices do v-for ?

Comment: Não sei se funciona com vuejs mas não seria algo como a expressão `{{ nomes.length - i }}: {{ nome }}`

Comment: Não deu muito certo, @AugustoVasques

Comment: Pra quem votou negativo se puder comentar o que posso melhorar na questão, ajuda muito.

Comment: Obrigado por aceitar a resposta. Em breve irei trazer algumas postagens sobre OL e sobre o `counter-increment:` para o SOpt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note que se a ideia é só exibição, você não precisa fazer nada no JavaScript, as listas em HTML já suportam indicadores que podem ser customizados, no caso usando a tag `<OL>` com o atributo `reversed`, exemplo:

```html
<ol reversed>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Baz</li>
</ol>
```

Não precisa nem usar [`Array.prototype.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), basta o próprio [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) no *array*, assim evita você até se atrapalhar (suponho, mas pode ser que você realmente deseje alterar TODOS os índices usando `unshift()`), exemplo:

```js
const HelloVueApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.items.push(Math.random());
    }, 500);
  },
}

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#exemplo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.39/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="exemplo">
  <ol reversed>
    <li v-for="item of items">
    {{item}}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Notem que é possível customizar o `OL` para trocar os números por outros tipos, como respondi em: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075034/1518921 e você também pode usar um pseudo-element `::before` (ou até o `::after`, dependendo do efeito que desejar) com a propriedade `counter-increment: ...` para estilizar o que será exibido no lugar dos indicadores nativos.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução aplicando o seguinte:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="(nome, i) in nomes">
      {{ nomes.length - i }}: {{ nome }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Com `nomes.length` recebo o tamanho do array e subtraio o valor do índice, obtendo o índice na ordem inversa, obtendo o resultado:

- 3: Guilherme
- 2: Victor
- 1: Leonardo

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73703990/19527215)

Comment: Olá Victor. Concordo que funciona, mas não atende necessariamente ao enunciado da sua pergunta: *Mas eu quero que os índices sejam invertidos*. Visualmente são apresentados os valores com um calculo simples de subtração, mas os índices não foram invertidos de fato. Entendo perfeitamente que o AR lhe forneceu algo que resolva visualmente no SOen, mas é justamente porque ele não se preocupou com o significado técnico do termo *"índice"* (index) e talvez você também não, soa como um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635).

Comment: Mas não foi exatamente o que o colega Augusto recomendou?

Comment: Sim @CypherPotato, foi exatamente o que o Augusto Vasques comentou, mas no momento mesmo que de fato não inverta o índice, visualmente já resolve meu problema, me contentei que não há como inverter de fato a ordem do índice, após a resposta do Augusto.